# Jackson Json Map or Key deserializer array data to Java hashmap<Integer,MyClass>

Tags: json, jackson, apache-camel

New to Jackson and json so I appologize if I'm not clear enough.

I've seen some references to Key and Map Deserializers that might be a better fit for what I want to do but I haven't been able to locate a concrete example on how these would be put together.

I am looking for the best way to deserialize a JSON Array into a Hashmap where the hashmap key is the one of the values is the passed JSON Array. This could either be a change in the JSON or a change in the serialization.

This is my current code design prototype. eventually this will be part of a camel route.

Parent class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "EligibilityUnit")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EligibilityUnit implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3456126687901598200L;
@XmlElement(name = "EligibilityUnitUUID")
protected int eligibilityUnitUUID;

@JsonProperty("eligibilityMembers")
@JsonDeserialize(using = Elig4Deserializer.class) // JSONtoMap2
protected   HashMap<Integer, EligibilityMember> eligibilityMembers;
public EligibilityUnit() {
    super();
    eligibilityUnitUUID =  Math.abs(UUID.randomUUID().hashCode());
    }

public Map <Integer,EligibilityMember> getEligibilityMembers() {
    return eligibilityMembers;
}
public void setEligibilityMembers(HashMap<Integer, EligibilityMember> eligibilityMembers) {
    this.eligibilityMembers = eligibilityMembers;
}
... getters/setters
}
```

Child class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "EligibilityMember")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EligibilityMember implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5943362268820173933L;
Integer personId;  
String firstName;
String lastName;
//... getters/setters
}
```

Test program

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    String json =               
            "{"+
                      "\"eligibilityMembers\": " +
                    "["+
                            "{"+
                            "\"personId\": 11,"+
                            "\"firstName\": \"Jane\","+
                            "\"lastName\": \"Jones\""+
                          "},"+
                          "{"+
                            "\"personId\": 12,"+
                            "\"firstName\": \"Tiffany\","+
                            "\"lastName\": \"Roberts\""+
                          "},"+
                          "{"+
                            "\"personId\": 13,"+
                            "\"firstName\": \"Janika\","+
                            "\"lastName\": \"Brown\""+
                          "}"+
                      "]"+
                    "}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);  
    Object map = mapper.readValue(json, EligibilityUnit.class);
    //Convert Map to JSON
     String jsonOut = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
     //Print JSON output
     System.out.println(jsonOut);

}
```

De-serialization Class

```
 public class Elig4Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
 public Elig4Deserializer() {
     super();

    }


@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = arg0.readValueAsTree();
    String json =  node.toString();
    Object map = null;
    Map<Integer,EligibilityMember> mapx = new HashMap<Integer,EligibilityMember>();

    CollectionType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory()
              .constructCollectionType(List.class, EligibilityMember.class);

    List<EligibilityMember> members =    mapper.readValue(json, javaType);

     for (EligibilityMember i : members) mapx.put(i.getPersonId(),i);
    return (Object) mapx;

}
```

}

This is the json from the class

```
{"eligibilityUnit":1062082797,"eligibilityMembers":{"11":   {"personId":11,"personSSN":null,"personNumber":null,"primeNumber":null,"individualId":null,"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Jones"},"12":{"personId":12,"personSSN":null,"personNumber":null,"primeNumber":null,"individualId":null,"firstName":"Tiffany","lastName":"Roberts"},"13":{"personId":13,"personSSN":null,"personNumber":null,"primeNumber":null,"individualId":null,"firstName":"Janika","lastName":"Brown"}}}
```

Is this the best way to handle this? I've seen a lot of partial solutions but nothing that quite matches what I am trying to do.

Realistically, I would prefer the JSON was something like this *(I understand the format on this my not be 100% correct I am posting it as where I would like to go. it is still a work in progress)*

`{"eligibilityMembers":
    [{
     "personId":11,
           {"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Jones",
                 "Income"
                       [{"IE-ME":
                            [{"Wages":1434.34,"support":535.99}],
                        "FS":
                            [{"Misc":60.00,"SSI":754.55}],
                        "CM":
                            [{"Support":535.99}],
                        }]
                "Expenses":
                       [{"IE-ME":
                            [{"Rent":908.90,"Utilities":45.99}],
                        "DCS":
                            [{"Misc":60.00,"ChildCare":754.55}]
                        }]
            },
     {"personId":12,
          {"firstName":"Tiffany","lastName":"Roberts"
                       "Income"
                       [{"IE-ME":
                            [{"Wages":1.34}],
                        "FS":
                            [{"SSD":50.55}],
                        "CSC":
                            [{"Support":535.99}],
                        }]
                "Expenses":
                       [{"IE-ME":
                            [{"Rent":400.15,"Utilities":80.86}] 
                        }]
          },
     {"personId":13, 
          {"firstName":"Janika","lastName":"Brown"}
     }]
}
}`

Comment: The JSON that you want is not valid.

Comment: I updated what I am looking for in the JSON. The point is I am looking for some solid deserialization examples using key or map deserialization.  If those fit what I am trying to do I will tweak the JSON to match